# How to get past this valueError: Unrecognized character O in format string?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

**The code I am writing extracts info from the excel file. Notes the names down and saves it for creating an array with the same name as column name. Then it counts the number of "null" character in the list and removes those nulls. Then it prints the length of the data column to be plotted and creates another array with the x-axis values in range from 1 to len(data column). After that it creates a plot and moves it to desired folder.**

```
home = "C:\\Users\\Ishita\\Desktop\\Thesis2\\Raw Data\\Before merger\\"

def count_null(list1, num):
    count = 0
    for element in list1:
        if(element == num):
            count = count + 1
    print("count of null is: ", count)
    return count

def create_text_file(file_col_write, file_col):
    with open(file_col_write, "w") as f:
        for item in file_col:
            f.write(str(item) + "\n")
def plot_and_move(file_col_copy, file_col_write, location_save):
    location_save_plot = home + name_of_file + file_col_copy + ".png"
    plt.plot(x, file_col_copy, color="green")
    plt.xlabel("Days")
    plt.ylabel("Price")
    plt.savefig(location_save_plot, bbox_inches="tight")
    if os.path.exists(location_save_plot):
        print("File exists")
        if os.path.exists(location_save):
            print("Folder exists")
            shutil.move(location_save_plot, location_save)
            shutil.move(file_col_write, location_save)
        else:
            os.makedirs(location_save)
            print("Folder created")
            shutil.move(location_save_plot, location_save)
            shutil.move(file_col_write, location_save)
    plt.show()  
def create_array(file_col, j, file_col_copy):
      file_col = []
      for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):
          file_col.append(sheet.cell_value(i,j))
      #print(file_col)
      for i in range(count_null(file_col, "null")):
          file_col.remove("null")
      #print(file_col)
      file_col_write = home + file_col_copy + ".txt"
      create_text_file(file_col_write, file_col)
      print("file_col length: ",len(file_col))
      file_col_length = len(file_col)-1
      return file_col_length

import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import shutil


location = home + "testfile-532276.BO.xls"
name_of_file = location.split("\\")[-1]
name_of_file = name_of_file.split(".")[0] + name_of_file.split(".")[1]
print(name_of_file)

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(location) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

print("Rows:", sheet.nrows)
print("Column:", sheet.ncols)
location_save = home + name_of_file

for j in range(1,5):
    file_col = sheet.cell_value(0,j)
    file_col_copy = sheet.cell_value(0,j)
    print(file_col)
    length = create_array(file_col, j, file_col_copy)    
    x = []
    for i in range(0, length+1):
        x.append(i)
    print("length of x:", len(x))
    #print("x:", x)
    file_col_write = home + file_col_copy + ".txt"
    plot_and_move(file_col_copy, file_col_write, location_save)
```

***Error message***
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Ishita/Desktop/Thesis2/copy-02.py', wdir='C:/Users/Ishita/Desktop/Thesis2')

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Ishita/Desktop/Thesis2/copy-02.py", line 86, in 
    plot_and_move(file_col_copy, file_col_write, location_save)

File "C:/Users/Ishita/Desktop/Thesis2/copy-02.py", line 25, in plot_and_move
    plt.plot(x, file_col_copy, color="green")

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2789, in plot
    is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 1666, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 225, in **call**
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 366, in _plot_args
    linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 106, in _process_plot_format
    'Unrecognized character %c in format string' % c)

ValueError: Unrecognized character O in format string

￼

Comment: Always post **whole error message** with **full traceback** please.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `file_col_copy` is a string. The function `plt.plot()` expects arguments in many different format, but usually, you want to pass `plt.plot(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are both arrays, not strings.

Comment: It helped. The file_col was  a problem as I was not returning it when creating an array.